# FFMPEG transcoding failing on cur_dts is invalid

Tags: ffmpeg, video, rtmp

I'm transcoding RTMP input from NGINX ingesting server to UDP TS stream h264 & mp2 with ffmpeg and SW enconder libx264. From time to time, transcoding process hang on the initialization and don't start.

The command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1/ingesting -c:a mp2 -c:v libx264 -ar 48000 -profile:v main -x264opts interlaced=1:nal-hrd=cbr -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -vf scale=720x576,setdar=16/9,format=yuv420p,fps=fps=25,setfield=mode=tff -flags +ilme+ildct -streamid 0:0x201 -streamid 1:0x202 -mpegts_pmt_start_pid 0x200 -mpegts_start_pid 0x203 -metadata:s:a:0 language="" -mpegts_service_id 2 -mpegts_transport_stream_id 9217 -metadata provider_name="PNAME" -metadata service_name="SNAME" -minrate 2M -maxrate 2M -bufsize 1500k -muxrate 2600k -f mpegts -pcr_period 30 -b:v 2M "udp://239.1.67.71:1234?pkt_size=1316&bitrate=2600000&dscp=34&localaddr=10.61.5.10"
```

FFMPEG is compiled from latest git, with CUDA GPU support, but not used in this transcoding process.

`ffmpeg version N-100673-g553eb07737 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6) configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --enable-static --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-filters --enable-openssl`

With log level debug I get following error:

```
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (513) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
```

Full log is here: https://pastebin.com/nC7GFcf4

UPDATE:
This problem occurs only with latest git version from master branch (N-100673-g553eb07737). With release 4.3 (n4.3.1-221-gd08bcbffff) this problem does not occur.

Comment: No need for `-re` for live inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding `--enable-parser=h264 --enable-parser=acc` to configure command line did the trick. Maybe you need another parser. The command `configure --list-parsers` lists all the available parsers to enable.